# Facebook's api- wall updates(photo) with hover state

Tags: php, javascript, ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm not sure if this is the best place to ask this question but how does pict.com post a photo that has an hover effect on the user's facebook feed? I've been researching for 2 days now, i know facebook can allow a third party app to post status updates, photos etc to a user's wall(with their consent of course), but how to make that image have an hover effect, i have no clue. I would love to build something like this if i can get a nudge in the right direction. 
Thanks 
ref 
pict.com 
http://blog.pict.com

Comment: Sorry, which hover effect are you talkin' about? Would it be possible to post a screenshot of with hover and without it?

I've been looking through the site for something like you've talked about, but did not find anything.

Answer (score 0):

If the image is hovering on the users actual facebook wall, this might be a browser extension, from my work with the facebook api, (which was around 1 year ago), it would be impossible due to security reasons, my code running on a users wall,

The image will have a hover effect on the app, but once posted on the wall the hover effect will disappear, due to being controlled by a different code,